# Google GSON not parsing JSON in Java retrieved from a WebMethod in a C# website

Tags: java, android, json, gson, webmethod

I have an ASP.NET website that uses C# to create JSON via a WebMethod, the webmethod is then called from a Java android application via an http post. I provide the webmethod with a page id and it returns the page contents, in this case it returns the content for an error page.

This is the JSON returned by the webmethod:

```
D/WebInterface( 2353): {"d":[{"intId":2418,"strName":"Error 404","strTitle":"Ooo
ps, I couldn\u0027t find that!","strSummary":"Error 404, I couldn\u0027t find th
e page you\u0027re looking for.","strBody":"\u003cp\u003eYou could try browsing
the website or checking that you typed the URL correctly, if you came to this pa
ge from another site, please let me know and thanks for visiting.\u003c/p\u003e"
,"strUpdateDate":null,"strCreateDate":null}]}
```

I use Google GSON in my Android app to create an object from the JSON but it returns null no matter what I do. Here is my Google GSON method:

```
public static Containerdata resultsFromJson(String json)
{
    try
    {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

        Containerdata results = gson.fromJson(json, Containerdata.class);

        Log.d("WebInterface", "RETURNING OBJECT FROM JSON");

        return results;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("WebInterface", "Error: Malformed JSON.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

This method returns Containerdata which is below:

```
public class Containerdata {
    public List<Containerdata.Node> d;

    public class Node
    {
        int intId;
        String strName;
        String strTitle;
        String strSummary;
        String strBody;
        String strUpdateDate;
        String strCreatedate;
    }
}
```

Containerdata returned by resultsFromJson is always null no matter what I do to the json returned by the webmethod and I have no idea why. This is the method that gets my JSON from my WebMethod:

```
// Gets json in the form of a string from a web service
public static String dataFromWeb(String url, String postData)
{
    Log.d("WebInterface", "Loading from web");
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection httpcon = (HttpURLConnection) ((new URL(url).openConnection()));
        httpcon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httpcon.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        httpcon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpcon.connect();

        byte[] outputBytes = postData.getBytes("UTF-8");
        OutputStream os = httpcon.getOutputStream();
        os.write(outputBytes);

        os.close();

        InputStream response = httpcon.getInputStream();

        Log.d("WebInterface", Helpers.convertStreamToString(response));

        return Helpers.convertStreamToString(response);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("WebInterface", "failed from web... " + e.toString());

        return "";
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help and point me in the right direction, I'd be very greatful.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Note that it makes no difference what language is used to create the JSON.  It could be created by FORTRAN II on an 1130 and it shouldn't make any difference, so long as the JSON meets specs.

Comment: (The JSON string above appears to be valid.)

Comment: But note that you misspelled "strCreateDate".

Comment: I'm aware the language does not matter but I'm trying to give some background to my question. Also thanks for pointing out the typo.

Comment: **"This is the JSON returned by the webmethod"** - What you've posted matches neither of the `Log.d(...)` calls in the code you've shown. If  `resultsFromJson(...)` is returning `null` it actually suggests there may be an exception being thrown. Are you sure logcat isn't showing the "Error: Malformed JSON." message? At the very least, use `e.printStackTrace()` in the `catch` block.

Comment: It's not reaching the malformed json statement. I've tested to see if its getting to the catch statement but it's not. It's as if gson has done what it needs to do then returned null anyway.

Comment: FWIW, your code works for me, with the JSON data shown.

Comment: @LukeAlderton : My main point was what you'd shown as the JSON returned. It starts `D/WebInterface( 2353):` then shows the string. That isn't from the code you posted, where did it come from?

Comment: @Squonk Sorry, thats from the logcat I forgot to remove that.

Comment: @Perception why would it work for you and not for me? Could I see how you've implemented it?

Comment: @LukeAlderton : I realise that it's from logcat but it's obviously being logged somewhere else other than the code you've shown. You haven't shown us how the JSON string is retrieved and passed to your `resultsFromJson(...)` method. It seems something is breaking in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Sorry I've added the method to my original question that gets the JSON from the web, I log the JSON here.

Comment: @LukeAlderton - if you have Maven, you can clone [this repo](https://github.com/sevenhillsoftware/stackoverflow) and view the test code (look at class misc.stack.json.GsonTest).

Comment: @LukeAlderton : In your `dataFromWeb(...)` method comment out `Log.d("WebInterface", Helpers.convertStreamToString(response));` and try running your code again. I think you're reading past end of stream in your second call to `Helpers.convertStreamToString(response)` (when you attempt to return the string).

Comment: Okay for some reason it's working, any idea why that worked? Also can you make an answer so I can mark it correct?

Comment: @LukeAlderton - you can't re-read an http response stream. Your Log method consumed the response, leaving nothing for the return call.

Comment: Ah okay, that makes sense. Could you post an answer explaining this please?

Comment: @LukeAlderton : Answer posted. That was a nasty one to track down - made similar mistakes myself.

Comment: Yeah doesn't help when you get stuck on something and then you seem to dwell on it for hours. It usually helps to just leave it for a few hours but it was annoying me so I needed to get it answered hah.

Comment: @LukeAlderton : It happens to all of us - not being able to see the forest for the trees. Sometimes you just need somebody else's eyes to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the following code...

```
InputStream response = httpcon.getInputStream();

Log.d("WebInterface", Helpers.convertStreamToString(response));

return Helpers.convertStreamToString(response);
```

You're basically trying to read the `InputStream` twice. The first time is when you log the response and the second time is when you try to `return` the response. The problem is you can't read a stream when it has already been read (OK, you *can* but that requires different code).

If you want to log the response then read the string locally and then log it and return it...

```
InputStream response = httpcon.getInputStream();

String responseString = Helpers.convertStreamToString(response);
Log.d("WebInterface", responseString);

return responseString;
```